# Disable woocommerce image sizes if image is not uploaded to product post type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible for woocommerce to create thumbnails only if an image is added to a product?

I have a blog and a shop on woocommerce. The blog produces dozens of posts per month with multiple images. The shop only has a few products. Every time I add photos to the blog then woocommerce creates custom thumbnails of these photos completely unnecessarily. As a result I have dozens of gigabytes of thumbnails that are completely unnecessary.

Is there any function that would block woocommerce from creating thumbnails if photos are uploaded to other post types than product?

I was trying something like this byt it diabled woocommerce thumbnails even if the photo is uploaded to a product:

```
function disable_wc_thumbnails_for_non_products( $sizes ) {
    global $post;
    
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'product' ) {
        unset( $sizes['woocommerce_thumbnail'] ); 
        unset( $sizes['woocommerce_single'] );
        unset( $sizes['woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail'] );
    
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'disable_wc_thumbnails_for_non_products' );
```

Comment: The image is generated on upload. What could work is to disable all woo sizes by default. And check if you upload image from Add/Edit page of product post type maybe ? But if you upload the image trough media library wont have these image sizes.